# why the code to insert a node at the nth position in a linked list not working for me?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have written below code to insert a node at nth position. I have gone through a blog that explains the insertion in c language. But I am trying to implement it in python. So may be I am doing something wrong.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class linkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None

    def createLL(self, value):
        newNode = node(value)
        if self.first is None:
            self.first = newNode
        else:
            tmp = self.first
            while tmp.next != None:
                tmp = tmp.next
            tmp.next = newNode

    def insert_after_node(self, value, pos):
        newNode = node(value)
        tmp = self.first
        for i in range(0, pos - 1):
            tmp = tmp.next
        newNode.next = tmp.next
        tmp.next = newNode


if __name__ == '__main__':

    view_ll = linkedList()
    view_ll.createLL(10)
    view_ll.createLL(20)
    view_ll.createLL(30)
    view_ll.createLL(40)
    view_ll.createLL(50)
    view_ll.createLL(60)
    print("The count is: ", view_ll.counting_nodes())
    print()
    print(view_ll.insert_after_node(900, 3))
    print("The count is: ", view_ll.counting_nodes())
```

Below are the point that I have tried to implement:

```
to insert a node after a particular node, we need to know or do following:
1) we need to create a new node with a value in it "{newNode = node(value)}".
2) Now, suppose we need to insert the new node after the 4th node in the LL. So, we also need a 
   pointer over the 4th node #   as well. Since we cannot have a pointer directly over the 4th node. 
   Therefore, we need to have temp pointer p over the #   very first node and traverse the LL and 
   move the pointer over the 4th node."p = self.first"
3) We also need to point the new node to the 5th node. This is because we are inserting the new node 
   after the 4th node.
4) The 4th node should point to the new node.
5) newNode's.next should point on the node, whose address is mentioned in the node where temp pointer 
   p is pointing.
6) p.next should point to the newNode.
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\Documents\linked_list.py", line 82, in <module>
    print(view_ll.insert_after_node(900, 3))
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\Documents\linked_list.py", line 36, in insert_after_node
    newNode.next = tmp.next
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell the previous node to point to new node.

```
class linkedList:
    # ...
    def createLL(self, value):
        newNode = node(value)
        if self.first is None:
            self.first = newNode
        else:
            tmp = self.first
            previous = tmp
            while tmp.next != None:
                previous = tmp
                tmp = tmp.next
            tmp = newNode
            previous.next = tmp
```

Comment: I don't think it is working. I am getting error. Another things is, if you do not point the pervious node to the new node, how the new node is going to appear after the previous node?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. What error? I meant that you should point previous node to the new node, because it wasn't done in your code.

Comment: I have pointed the previous node to the new node. In the function "insert_after_node" last two line is what is performing the task. In my ex. I am inserting new node between 4th and 5th node. So, Ideally I will have to first point the new node to the 5th node, and since the 5th node's address is in the 4th node. So I will have to use the "newNode.next = tmp.next". May be my assumption is wrong.

Comment: But in `createLL` you don't add at the end. It's like creating a few new nodes and not adding them to the list. Therefore your list only consists of 1 element. When you try to add something at 2 or further positions, you're getting an error. No nodes after the 1st one exist.

Comment: Sorry, after giving a good look at my code again I realized that in the function "create_LL" last line which is outside the while loop had a mistake. instead of "tmp.next = newNode", I had written "tmp = newNode". Which I have corrected in my original post. So, now even with out the extra variables "previous" also my code will create 6 nodes. Please try it to authenticate.